# Map a key between Apple and Logitech keyboards

Tags: mac, keyboard, boot-camp

I am using MBP 2015 running Catalina.
I am using external keyboard Logitech.
I installed Windows 10 with Boot Camp.
I have a problem to switch between OS's using software. The only option is to hold 'option/alt' key on MBP keyboard.
Mostly all keys are correctly mapped to Logitech but I realized that holding the key on MBP works but it does not work on external keyboard.
I assume that mapping for this key is wrong.
How could I fix it?
Thanks

Comment: alt/opt ought to be the same physical key on both OSes, whether you're on a Windows or Mac mapped keyboard. There's no way at boot to inject any type of code to change this. Why not use the Startup Disk control panel to swap - that's what it's for.

Comment: Right, Since I'm using wireless keyboard it might be the case of timing or etc. On Mac to use Startup Disk is not convenient but at least it could be solution. But I'm stuck on Windows. I don't have any workaround to boot in Mac when I'm on Windows

Comment: If you think it could be timing then tap it repeatedly rather than hold, & see if it's recognised… or you'll have to use the laptop keyboard instead. The control panel is the obvious way to work around it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could disregard my question because I found that's nothing to do with keyboard mappings.
I noticed that when it boots and I keep/hold the key but almost 'press it down' it works in most cases.

Sound like connectivity issue.
Thanks